# Magento 1.9.2 - Display 6 or 8 products in the same row

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, product-list

I declared a specific category in the dashboard of account in Magento but the list shows only 4 products for row. How can I display 6 or 8 products for row?

This is my code

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_list")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list.phtml")->setCategoryId('105')->toHtml();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getColumnCount() function is used to get the number of columns to be visible per row. So you can use setColumnCount() function to set the column count value.

You can use this code to show 6 products per row:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_list")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list.phtml")->setCategoryId('3')->setColumnCount(6)->toHtml();?>
```

You can change the value 6 to 8 in setColumnCount() function to show 8 products per row.

Comment: I tried man but i see ever 4 products for row in my dashboard...why?

Comment: Have you refreshed cache after making the changes, because I first tested the code in my localhost before posting here.

Comment: I cleared cache but i see ever 4 products for row.

Comment: Then I think you have modifications in the list.phtml or List.php file.

Comment: Any modifications in list.phtml or list.php for display the products in row. In list.phtml i have the standard code for the columns: $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();

Comment: @Gabriel91, can you share the code which you have written?

Comment: The code of list.phtml or in my dashboard where i call my category?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79492/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-arora-and-gabriel91).